# Балансировка троичного дерева

Tags: c++, дерево, балансировка

Не могу понять, что такое балансировка, а конкретнее как ее реализовать в программе для троичного дерева. Каков вообще ее алгоритм?

Вот есть у меня готовое троичное дерево, как мне теперь сделать для него балансировку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем случае балансировка дерева - это такая его организация, при которой длина разных его веток одинакова, или отличается ну совсем мало.

Пример:

```
        30
      /    \
     20     40
    / \      
   10  25  
  /  \
 5    15
```

При такой организации длина левой ветки больше правой (в этом примере на 2, но в реальных наборах данных длина может отличаться куда больше). А это значит, (в практическом смысле, например), что поиск элемента с ключом "5" займёт больше времени, чем поиск элемента с ключом "40".

Цель балансировки - организовать дерево так, чтобы длины веток (или глубина дерева, etc) при разных наборах данных были схожи. Например, вот это же дерево можно представить так:

```
      20
    /   \
  10     30
 /  \    / \
5   15  25  40
```

А с троичными деревьями всё куда интересней :) Мы можем пытаться оптимизировать дерево по нескольким критериям (по размеру, например), если очень хочется. Но на скорости поиска это никак не скажется. Вот цитата из статьи [Ternary Search Trees](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/ternary-search-trees/184410528) (Dr. Dobb's):

> **Better Insertion Orders**
>
> In what order should you insert the nodes into a tree? No matter in
>   what order you insert the nodes, you end up with the same digital
>   search trie -- **the data structure is totally insensitive to insertion
>   order**. Binary search trees are at the opposite end of the spectrum: If
>   you insert the nodes in a good order (middle element first), you end
>   up with a balanced tree. If you insert the nodes in sorted order, the
>   result is a long skinny tree that is very costly to build and search.
>   Fortunately, if you insert the nodes in random order, a binary search
>   tree is usually close to balanced.
>
> Ternary search trees fall between these two extremes. You can build a
>   completely balanced tree by inserting the median element of the input
>   set, then recursively inserting all lesser elements and greater
>   elements. A simpler approach first sorts the input set. The recursive
>   build function inserts the middle string of its subarray, then
>   recursively builds the left and right subarrays. We use this method in
>   our experiments; it is fast and produces fairly well-balanced trees.
>   The cost of inserting all words in a dictionary with function insert3
>   is never more than about 10 percent greater than searching for all
>   words. *D.D. Sleator and R.E. Tarjan describe **theoretical** balancing
>   algorithms for ternary search trees in "Self-Adjusting Binary Search
>   Trees" (Journal of the ACM, July 1985)*.

Про ++ не скажу, вот, вроде тут [на C наглядно](http://kvodo.ru/avl-tree.html), с примерами кода для балансировки бинарных деревьев.

Comment: Интересно, а балансировка как в двоичном дереве (скажем, АВЛ) даст сбалансированное троичное? (в нем же, по сути, средний (по равенству) путь IMHO на скорость поиска вообще не влияет).

Comment: Да не особо должно влиять. Вот [тут](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/ternary-search-trees/184410528?pgno=20) пишут, например: *D.D. Sleator and R.E. Tarjan describe **theoretical** balancing algorithms for ternary search trees in "Self-Adjusting Binary Search Trees" (Journal of the ACM, July 1985).* P.S. [Развлекаюсь](https://github.com/klopp/TTree/) вот потихоньку :)

Comment: Первая ссылка кривая оказалась, вот правильная: http://www.drdobbs.com/database/ternary-search-trees/184410528?pgno=2

Comment: @klopp: Круто, я нигде не видел русскоязычных обсуждений троичного дерева.